# Optimizing rank() query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm using the following query, within a stored procedure, to get user's ranking.

While trying to optimize the database, I’m trying to determine if this query can be optimize as it is the most used query in my database.

id column is indexed.

```
SELECT 
    @p_rank = all_time_rank 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         user_rankings.*, 
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS all_time_rank
     FROM 
         user_rankings) t
WHERE 
    id = @p_id;
```

Is there any way to get this query to perform better?

Comment: Preferably I would like to get the highest ranking for the user. If users ranked 10-20 all scored 1,000 points, I would like to display 10 as a result.

Comment: @dnoeth that's what he wants though, the 'RANK' of that userId - he doesn't care who it is ahead of him to create that rank

Comment: @dnoeth - I only posted that because I can't add anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase this as:

```
SELECT @p_rank = COUNT(*) + 1
FROM user_rankings ur
WHERE ur.score > (SELECT ur2.score FROM user_rankings ur2 WHERE ur2.id = @pid);
```

You would want an index on `user_rankings(id, score)`  and `user_rankings(score)`.

I think this will have somewhat better performance.

Comment: Thank you!
I didn’t add the new indexes yet, but executing the former query and the suggested new one resulted in this:
Original query:
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 172 ms,  elapsed time = 349 ms.

modified per your suggestion:
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 32 ms,  elapsed time = 37 ms.